# Git - Error when trying to commit code From Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, git, web, model-view-controller

I've created a new dynamic web project in eclipse and am trying to connect it to a repository. I follow the steps of creating the git repository for the project and the project gets added to the proper directory I set for the repository.

The issue is when I try to commit the files I keep getting an error: "Error occurred computing Git commit diffs
Missing unknown 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000".

I have no idea how to fix this. I've tried creating new repositories for the project and this issue keeps arising.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: What version of Eclipse (most importantly, what version of egit / jgit)? Old versions had issues like this (I saw something similar with Gerrit once)

Answer (score 0):

Pending you updating Eclipse and Egit to the latest version, double-check your status and Git operation in command line, installing [a native Git](https://git-scm.com/downloads).
The workaround (again, pending fixing Egit on Eclipse) would then be:

```
cd /path/to/repository
git status

# if needed:
git add .
git commit -m "Try and commit"
```

Answer (score 0):

Making sure you have enough disks pace and restarting eclipse should do the trick.